# Switch debugging to another project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have simple condole application in project `A`, that uses `dll` created in another project `B`. Both projects are in current solution. I start debugging console application and would like to continue debugging in `B` `dll` project when executable calls it's function. Currently `dll` release version is copied to project `Debug` folder. How to achieve debug continue in `dll` project `B` when started in console application of project `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your DLL with debug information, copy `.pdb` file along with `.dll` to the folder where debugger will see it. But be prepared, that Release configuration is built with optimizations, so you may not see the values of the variables (or see incorrect values), some breakpoints may not work and when you step into/over the debugger may jump forward and backward awkwardly. So generally it is possible to debug Release configurations, but it's much more easier to use Debug configuration for that.